# How to and where to free memory C++?

Tags: c++, linked-list, heap-memory

Hello I'm new to c++ and trying to grasp the memory management in it with the free() and delete. I have this add_flat function which works fine until I try to free the memory. I created an FlatList object and added the flats .Without the delete statement it works fine but after I put it the Head just returns some garbage value. Should I define a destructor ? I'm very new in c++ so any help would be appreciated.

```
void FlatList::add_flat(int index,int initial_bandwith,int flat_id) {

    Flat* new_flat = new Flat() ;

    new_flat->id = flat_id ;
    new_flat->initial_bandwidth = initial_bandwith ;
    new_flat->is_empty = false ;

    Flat* current = Head ;

    if (index == 0 ) {

        new_flat->next_Flat = Head ;
        Head->prev_Flat = new_flat ;
        Head = new_flat ;

    }

    else {

        for (int i = 0 ; i < index ; i++) {

            current = current->next_Flat ;

        }

        current->prev_Flat->next_Flat = new_flat ;
        new_flat->prev_Flat = current->prev_Flat ;
        current->prev_Flat = new_flat ;
        new_flat->next_Flat = current ;

    }

    delete new_flat;

}
```

```
FlatList b ;

b.add_flat(0,10,1) ;
cout << b.Head->id ;
```

Comment: *"Should I define a destructor ? "* - yes you should

Comment: does the line `Flat* current = Head ;`  work ? where is `Head` declared?

Comment: you destructor could be set by default, it depends on the class members

Comment: do you **need** to use `new` ? can't you just create an instance of you object?

Comment: So you create a new `Flat` and save its address into `new_flat`, `index` is 0 so you save its address into `Head`, then you delete `new_flat` (invalidating the address in `Head`), then with `cout << b.Head->id ;` you try to access that invalid address. Boom!

Comment: Try to minimize the use of new/delete (they are often not needed). For collection of objects there are containers like std::vector. And it looks like you could use something like [std::list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) here instead. And then your struct doesn't even need a next pointer and only needs to contain data (better separation of concerns too)

Comment: @Ivan Head is declared in the FlatList class and it works. I tried not to use new keyword but that didnt work.

Comment: It does not make sense to allocate a new node `new Flat()`, add it into the linked list, and then `delete` it at the end of the function. You delete the nodes when they are no longer in the list, not when they are still in the list.

Comment: @FabiosaysReinstateMonica Hmm I understood but so what is solution here Should I just not delete ?

Comment: @UygarMutlu In this function, you should not delete. Elsewhere in your program (like the destructor for instance) you should delete.

Comment: Observation: `add_flat` should reasonably leave you with one more `Flat` than you had before calling it. However, you create one (`new Flat()`) and destroy one (`delete new_flat`), so you still have as many as you started with.

Comment: https://youtu.be/JfmTagWcqoE

Comment: @john so if I delete the node in a different remove method is it ok and won't cause any leak ?

Comment: @UygarMutlu That sounds fine to me, but you should also write a destructor, to delete any nodes that are still left on the linked list when you are done with it.

Comment: If you delete nodes in a remove method, then the destructor can just call the remove method until the list is empty.

Comment: @john ok i will do that thanks for help in short notice.

Comment: Thank you guys all for the help I think I got it. Have a nice day everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Memory *must* be deallocated

- when you are sure that the data it holds is no more needed,
- before you drop all pointers that are referring to it.

If we take the case of a linked list, as long as you insert nodes, you must keep them. When you suppress one of the nodes, you can delete its allocated memory because you don't want this element anymore. Anyway, it is pointed to by the predecessor element or the list head. Hence you must redirect either the pointer of the preceding element or the list head to the node that follows.

Keeping pointer coherence requires great care as there can be tricky corner cases. If you forget to delete, you get a memory leak. If you forget to redirect some pointer, you get a dangling reference and a potential crash.